# making an app thats not violating any copyright laws

Tags: android

I am an amateur android developer. I have been developing for some months and now I am planning to release some apps on google play store once ready. But since I am an independent developer its difficult for me to design my icons and backgrounds. And my understanding is that I can't use just any icons or pictures from net because of copyright matters(correct me if I am wrong). So please suggest me some way to solve this problem(or how can I get copyright free resources). Also refer some articles that can be helpful in avoiding legal issues.I tried searching but http://developer.android.com/legal.html is the only helpful article I found but it didn't help with my concern.and if u find that this question is off topic in this forum, can u tell where can i get answers?

Comment: Look for the phrases "free", "royalty free", "public domain", "creative commons", amongst others.

Answer (score 2):

I am getting my icons and images from http://pixabay.com/ which contains only royalty free images.

Answer (score 0):

This may get flagged for being a question about legal advice (I've been flagged for that before). I've had some success searching for public domain art, which is completely free and legal to use for any purposes. I then edit the colors/content of that art to fit my needs. There are great resources out there if you look. I've had good luck with [OpenClipart](https://openclipart.org/tags/public%20domain) and [Clker](http://www.clker.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Use the below link

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

You can create your own Launcher icon, resources for icons, icons for action bar and also a set of resources which can be used for different views like button, checkbox, radio button, etc.

Hope this helps.